# Unable to calculate HTML element's half width/height due to CSS positioning

Tags: css, angular, css-position

I have a lot of trouble with this all the time. I'm using Angular and trying to write some code to add some elements to the DOM and then set their left and top based on  half width/height of another elements, but based on the CSS positioning I'm having trouble getting the correct values.

Following is the relevant CSS and resultant HTML, this is not representative of how the angular files are set up, I've simply combined the relevant CSS and HTML into this listing. I know that it has to do with all of the absolutely position elements, but I'm unclear how to add any wrapping divs to get what I want.

In the app-hud component, I'm using the Angular Renderer2 to create the child images of the hud component, then adding to the DOM and trying to position them in the middle of a pool.

Think of it as a deck of a cards. The pool (deck) holds the resources (cards). And then the HUD should center on the deck. I need to programmatically add and position these as I'll also be programming animations for the elements as well.

```
// styles
app-root, app-game {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

app-game {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

app-pool {
  position: absolute;
}

.resources {
  position: absolute;
}

app-resource {
  position: absolute;

  & img {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

app-hud {
  position: absolute;

  & img {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

=======================================

// Displayed HTML in the browser

<app-root> // browser width/height
  <app-game> // browser width/height
    <app-pool> // width/height = 0
      <div class="resources"> // width/height = 0
         <app-resource> // width/height = 0
           <img /> // width/height = actual width/height of img
         </app-resource>
      </div>
      <app-hud> // width/height = 0
        // I would like this img element to be positioned in the middle of the app-pool element
        <img /> // width/height = actual width/height of img
      </app-hud>
    </app-pool>
  </app-game>
</app-root>
```

And here is the app-hud component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-hud',
    templateUrl: './hud.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hud.component.css']
})
export class HudComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ContentChildren(HudDirective) hudActions: QueryList<HudDirective>;

    constructor(
        private _renderer: Renderer2,
        // app-hud element
        private _el: ElementRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        for (let action of this.hudActions) {
            const img: HTMLImageElement = this._renderer.createElement('img');
            img.src = action.image;
            img.width = img.height = 50;
            this._renderer.setStyle(img, 'position', 'absolute');

            // just to make sure i can position and this works
            this._renderer.setStyle(img, 'left', `50px`); 

            // doesn't work since _el.nativeElement.height has no value
            this._renderer.setStyle(img, 'top', `${this._el.nativeElement.height * 0.5}px`); 
            this._renderer.appendChild(this._el.nativeElement, img);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the height of an element to center it inside a div. Do something like the below:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
}

.element {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I do though, because I need to do this programmatically. What I posted is jsut the simplest examplee of my app. I could set styles using the renderer, but I eventually will need pixel values for advanced animations

Comment: Can't you just rename the `.element` class name to be something like `.absolute-center` and just add that class to any image you want to center instead of calculating everything?

Comment: I edited my comment, because it wasn't representative of what I meant if you didn't see the updated comment. I absolutely need the pixel values at some point.

Comment: I also can't use the solution given. I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Since the parent (pool) still has no width or height, positioning the hud's left and top at 50% does nothing and the transform then centers it at the 0, 0 mark of the pool element rather than true center.